My question is not listed on my question list
This query is for Stack overflow administrators. I have asked a question in stack overflow  How to call a C# DLL with custom type input from Powershell. This is answered & marked it as answered. But this does not get shown on my question list. Also points received by me also not get added. Please help me on this

Different accounts (notice different avatar images) -- one is 5 months old, the other 5 days old.

You have two separate accounts.  The one used to post this is 5 days old, while the one used to post the linked question is 5 months old.
You should probably file a request for staff to merge these accounts.

@GajananaDS See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact (choose "I need to merge user profiles" under "Account Issue")

Moderators can't merge accounts. That can only be done by staff. Account merges should be requested through the "Contact"/"Contact Us" link that is in the footer of every page, and which samcarter has linked above.
